# How to find padding space around the label text?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, label

I am adding a label controls at run time. I can add or modify text in label and can change the font also.Now my problem is When i changed the font of text in label, alignment is not proper,its due to padding.Is there any way to find how much padding is ocured [ed: obscured?] based on font?

Comment: This is going to require a screenshot to demonstrate exactly what is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Did you look at the `Padding` property?

You may have to turn off `AutoSize` to get better results.

Comment: yeah, i tried with setting paading to 0px and Autosize to false, but no luck. Padding is caused based on font i use for the label text. SO is there any way to get how much padding spaces occured for purticular font type?

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't you call `TextRenderer.MeasureText`?

If you provide the correct target size (being the rectangle that the label can occupy), you should be able to find out how much space the text will occupy/has occupied.